# Spotify Folder in "My Documents"

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to make an app for Spotify, but I can't get the first step to work. I have made a folder named 'Spotify' in 'My Documents' (I use Windows 7 64 Bit), and made a folder inside it named 'test'. In 'test' I put a file 'index.html' to test if I can open it in Spotify, but I can't. I have a developer account, so that can't be a problem. When I type 'spotify:app:test' in the search bar, I get something like this:

[image: http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/7153/spotifyh.png]

(Note, in the screenshot it says spotify:app:tutorial, but I get the exact same result as displayed when I type spotify:app:test, saying failed to load application)

Also, I use Spotify version 0.8.7.111.gaf8d06ed-245

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotify cannot load an application unless it has a valid manifest file. The manifest documentation can be found [here](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/#applicationmanifest).

Alternatively, see the [Spotify Apps Tutorial](https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial) app for a working example of a valid manifest. Note that you at least need an identifier, version and name for a manifest to be considered valid.